# Does a previous overstay in Canada appear on my record if travelling with a new passport?

Tags: canada, uk-citizens, overstaying, passport-stamps

I am flying from the UK with a UK passport. I would like to know what does passport control see on their screens when they put though my passport?

I have travelled to Canada before on my old passport and I did not get my flight back after 3 weeks and I went travelling around I stayed for 98 days I got my flight back to UK no problem and I never got question as they don't have a stamp on exit.

This was in 2011 I now have new passport and I would like to go to Canada for a friends wedding and I was wondering if I will get red flag this this time ? As I over stayed my stamp I think I am only covered for 90 days not to sure.

Comment: Border guards can typically search by name and birth date if they wish, I would be surprised if the databases used in Canada would not allow that. They might not see a big flashing red light and might not bother looking further but I am pretty sure they can find out.

Comment: If you were only in Canada for 98 days, why do you believe you overstayed?

Answer (score 6):

To answer your actual question, probably.  If the authorities notice an overstay, they presumably record it in a database where it is not tied to a specific document, but rather to your identity: name, date and place of birth, etc.  Surely they are aware that passports expire and are replaced.

However: Are you certain that you overstayed?  See http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?q=1016&t=16.

Quote (emphasis added):

> ### How long can I stay in Canada as a visitor?
>
> A border services officer at the port of entry in Canada will determine how long you can stay in Canada. *Most visitors are allowed a six-month stay from the day they entered Canada.* If the officer authorizes a stay of less than six months, they will indicate in your passport the date by which you must leave Canada.

There may be no problem to solve here.

You say you "overstayed your stamp" but you also say you think you are covered for 90 days, so it is not clear whether the border guard indicated a departure date when he or she stamped your passport.  What does the stamp actually say?  Are there any written annotations on the stamp, and, if so, what do they say?

Answer (score 4):

They do have access to the facts that someone with your same name did what you did.

One of my guides had an incident with immigration back in his college days (not over staying but arguing whether he had financial means to drive to Alaska from the lower 48). He is on his third passport since then and the issue still occasionally pops up when entering Canada.

Exactly what appears on their screens is not widely known as they like to avoid having you see what is on the screen, so can't confirm if that info shows automatically or is a secondary search they may run.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I am sure they will see on there data base etc I don't mind that etc.. Just wonder what would happen etc ? Well they let me in for 2 weeks ?

Comment: I have emailed the embassy they say they will email back in 24 hours :)